# how to pass parameter when different button call same class?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am developing for iPhone the app I am developing has many buttons and I want all buttons to call the same class but with different parameter

for example I want button1 to call the displayimageclass

and button2 should call the same class displayimageclass so, how to different method call same class and in that same class how to fetch different button from where it is call to particular class.

Answer (score 1):

That is pretty much standard. Just define as many IBAction methods as you need.

In the viewController's .h file:

```
- (IBAction)actionButton1:(UIButton *)sender;
- (IBAction)actionButton2:(UIButton *)sender;
- (IBAction)actionButton3:(UIButton *)sender;
```

And in its .m file:

```
{
    //react here to button1 pressed
}


- (IBAction)actionButton1:(UIButton *)sender
{
    //react here to button1 pressed
}

- (IBAction)actionButton2:(UIButton *)sender
{
    //react here to button2 pressed
}

- (IBAction)actionButton3:(UIButton *)sender
{
    //react here to button3 pressed
}
```

Then associate the action with the Button's events (TouchUpInside would be most appropriate, I guess).

Answer (score 1):

You should add tag property to your buttons. 
Suppose your buttons are

```
button1.tag =1;
button2.tag =2;
button3.tag =3;
```

When you click any button, NSLog shows related button tag number. i.e You will get your result what you want.

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {

        UIButton* button = (UIButton *)sender;
        NSLog(@"The number of tag:%d",button.tag);
    }
```

I think it will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

you can implement your action method like this:

```
- (IBAction)action:(UIButton *)sender
{
    //sender will be different for different button
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set tag value for buttons and get those buttons like

```
- (IBAction)action:(UIButton *)sender
{
  UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)sender;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for 
1) several buttons performing the same method with the same behavior
2) several buttons performing the same method but having different behavior based on the button characteristics
3) each button performing its own method.

1) You can register several buttons on the same IBAction, they all will call it and perform the same code
2) In the method were all the buttons are registered (cf: 1) it is possible to sort the buttons by subclassing the UIButton class, giving an enum value that represents what the button should perform and then in the called method check the enum value with a switch in order to trigger the wanted behavior

The UIBarButtonItem  already has this tag property so you could use them by giving a value to each of your UIBarButtonItem in the Interface Builder and set them to call the following method

```
- (IBAction) myButtonsMethod:(id)object
  if ([object isKindOfClass:[UIBarButtonItem class]])
  {
    switch ([(UIBarButtonItem *)object tag]) 
    {
      case myFirstTagValue
    ...
    }
```

3) @Hermann Klecker solution is the right one.